# Java HashTable Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashtable

I have a Java code which searches for values in the hash table in following way:

```
class HTDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hashtable balance = new Hashtable();
        double bal;
        balance.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34));
        balance.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22));
        balance.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00));
        balance.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22));
        balance.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08));

        **System.out.println("John Doe's balance: " + balance.get("John Doe"));**
        **System.out.println("Tom Smith's balance: " + balance.get("Tom Smith"));**
        **System.out.println("Jane Baker's balance: " + balance.get("Jane Baker"));**
    }
 }
```

Now, I want to run it on multiple thread i.e. I want to modify the code in such a way thus the get methods (inside **) works concurrently. Can anybody help me how to do that. Actually, I am facing issue with passing hash tables and making it concurrent while running.

Comment: Is your question - "how to create new threads?" or "How to handle multithreaded access to shared data safely?"

Comment: @DNA, second one. I want to know how to modify that code to handle it safely.

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. If you populate the map in a thread, and then start threads that only read from the map, you don't need to do anything. If you access it in read-write and are only interested in single entries at once, since Hashtable is synchonized, you don't need to do anything. In other scenarios (like adding or getting two entries atomically, then you need special synchronization. Your question is too vague to be answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashtable is synchronized and therefore already thread safe. You don't need anything else to access your code safely in a multi threaded environment.

However, HashTable is obsolete and its performance will be quite poor in a highly concurrent environment due to the thread-safety mechanism that is implemented (all methods are synchronized) and the provided iterators are not thread safe and will fail if you modify the table while iterating.

Bottom line: use a ConcurrentHashMap, and use generics if you can:

```
Map<String, Double> balance = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Double> ();
```

The rest of your code should remain unchanged.

One thing you also need to keep in mind, is that even with a thread safe data structue (be it a HashTable or a ConcurrentMap), you still need to deal with concurrency issues such as atiomcity.

For example, if you check the balance to authorise a payment like this:

```
double johnBalance = balance.get("John");
if(johnBalance > paymentAmount) 
    authorisePayment();
else
    declinePayment();
```

There is an atomicity issue: the balance on John's account might have changed between the call to `balance.get(...)` and the payment authorization.

If this is one of your use cases, you will need to introduce an additional layer of synchronization.

Comment: Even a ConcurrentHashMap doesn't necessarily make everything safe and correct magically. For example, if two entries in the map must be stored or retrieved atomically, external synchronization is still needed.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course - reading the question, I thought atomicity was not required but I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @JBNizet And hopefully this is an exercise - if not I'd like to know the name of the bank ;-)

Comment: I had the same impression, but wasn't 100% sure. The conclusion of your answer made me a little bit frightened. Maybe it's me, but I read it as: use a ConcurrentHashMap, and whatever you might do in the rest of the code, it will be correct. +1, though.

Comment: @JBNizet That was a fair comment.

Comment: HashTable is not thread safe. All it's methods are synchronized. It's not the same thing, and there's nothing 'very inefficient' about it.

Comment: @EJP I agree that *"very inefficient*" needs to be qualified. It is inefficient under high contention (see my edit). But Hashtable is thread safe, the same way that the Collections.synchronizedxxx are thread safe. However it does not provide enough guarantees to iterate in a thread safe way (I suppose that's what you mean) and require additional client side locking. But that does not make it not thread safe. BTW, both the javadoc and JCiP seem to agree on that point.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

> ...
>
> *A hash table supporting full concurrency of **retrievals** and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.*
>
> ...

To parallelize those three lines, you could simply do

```
String[] users = { "John Doe", "Tom Smith", "Jane Baker" };
for (final String user : users) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(user + "'s balance: " + balance.get(user));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

If you in fact have a slightly more complex scenario, I suggest you look into `ExecutorService` and related classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. All the methods of HashTable are synchronized. See the Javadoc. Use a HashMap, or, if you need thread *safety,* which you didn't mention, ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using Hashtable over hashmap is because you want to acceas your multithreaded environment. well these synchronized collections are now obsolete because they indeed cant' solve synchronization issues . They had actually atomized adding or rmoving .
 But they dont adress  a simple scenario that in map you will want firstt check whther the key exists before adding.

Collection.synchronozimap() was a step ahead to address concurrency issues.But they too failed in intensive multithreaded environmentt.

ultimately the preferred way is to use concurrent API .They adress some issues like I described above by a method ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent.

Comment: Collections.synchronizedMap() wasn't a 'step ahead'. It is a way of getting exactly the same behaviour as HashSet from a HashMap. It adds nothing. No progress: no step ahead.

Comment: whhhhhhhhhaaatt..!!!! exactly the same behaviour as HashSet from a HashMap. ????//.....can you quote some referance..?.

Comment: Err, the Javadoc? Can you quote some reference for 'a step ahead'? And given an example 'step'?